# Fetch data from two table in nodejs from mysql in rest Api

Tags: mysql, node.js

js Developers

I am trying to create Rest api in node.js . I want to get data from two table in mysql database. First table is **USERS** which contain **{id, name, email}** and Second table is **USERINFO** which contain **{id, mobile , address, user_id}** here **user_id** is work as **foreign key** that is associate with **USERS** table. In **USERINFO** table more than one information.

First table Look like this
[image]

Second Table look like this[image]

I got this type of output

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "abc",
    "email": "abc@xxx.com",
    "mobile": "11111",
    "address": "qqq",
    "user_id": 1
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "XYZ",
    "email": "xyz@xxx.com",
    "mobile": "22222",
    "address": "wwwww",
    "user_id": 2
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "abc",
    "email": "abc@xxx.com",
    "mobile": "3333333",
    "address": "ssssss",
    "user_id": 1
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "XYZ",
    "email": "xyz@xxx.com",
    "mobile": "444444",
    "address": "nnnnn",
    "user_id": 2
}]
```

But i want this type output

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "abc",
    "email": "abc@xxx.com",
    "info": [
        {
            "mobile": "11111",
            "address": "qqq",   
        },
        {
            "mobile": "3333333",
            "address": "ssssss",
        }
    ],        
    "user_id": 1
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "XYZ",
    "email": "xyz@xxx.com",
    "info": [
        {
            "mobile": "22222",
            "address": "wwwww",
        },
        {
            "mobile": "444444",
            "address": "nnnnn",
        }
    ],
    "user_id": 2
}]
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I can think of numerous ways this can be done. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Tik i am trying now simple query in mysql can you give me easy way to make this type of api

Comment: you wont be able to do this in mysql via a query.
you will need join the data in javascript

Comment: So give me the best way how can i do it.